# Not receiving expected attributes using `onProgress` callback on a react <video> element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a video element which I pass a url and a `onCanPlay` and `onProgress` callback.

```
<video
  url={url}
  onCanPlay={this.onCanPlay}
  onProgress={this.onProgress}
/>
```

The URL I am passing in in this case is from `window.URL.createObjectURL`. I do receive an `onProgress` event, but it does not have the properties of `lengthComputable`, `total`, and `loaded`.

```
onProgress = ({ lengthComputable, total, loaded }) => {
  console.log(lengthComputable, total, loaded);  // these are all undefined.
}
```

I am a little perplexed. [According to MDN, these events should exist on that trigger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/progress), so I am wondering if it is a quirk of React or if it is me doing something wrong.

How can I get the progress event of the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these properties are available on `nativeEvent`:

```
onProgress = ({ nativeEvent: { lengthComputable, total, loaded } }) => {
  console.log(lengthComputable, total, loaded);
}
```

The object you were trying to read properties from is [React's SynteticEvent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, for me the nativeEvent does not have the properties either. The event object should be the right one, it has `type: "progress"` but no `loaded` or `total` (Chrome 57 / Win, React 15.3.1)

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution, but it's not quite the same. We are dealing with what has been buffered, and there can be multiple buffered ranges (when the user seeked to a new position, there will be a new buffered range etc).

While this is useful for example to visualize which parts of the file have been loaded/buffered already, it is not very helpful when it comes to absolute loading progress.

Found on https://github.com/souporserious/react-media-player/blob/master/src/vendors/HTML5.jsx#L121 :

```
_handleProgress = ({ target: { buffered, duration } }) => {
    let progress = 0

    if (duration > 0) {
      progress = (buffered.end(buffered.length - 1) / duration)
    }

    this.props.onProgress(progress)
}
```

However, you quickly run into false progress values when loading ranges like `src="myfile.mp3#t=20,30"`. You won't start at 0%.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges